# Using the Do Calculation Action in SP Designer 2013

Tags: workflow

I have compiled a Stationery Stock List in SP 2013 based on a Custom List.

I am also using a SP Designer 2013 workflow in connection with an InfoPath 2010 Filler Form.

I would like to use a stage in the workflow to automatically deduct the amount of stock ordered from the stock quantity held in the list when a Stationery Request is submitted.

Am I right in thinking that I need to use the Do Calculation action based on those two fields in the Stationery Stock List?

Your help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `Do Calculation` action definitely can do what you need. If both values are stored in the same list item (the one that the workflow instance is working on) then it's very simple operation.

The other approach would be to use the Infopath formula to calculate the result. That way you won't need to use workflow for this operation.